# React Native 2x2, 3x3, 4x4 etc... (scalable grid) with gap and no spacing on the outside?

Tags: react-native

So I have gotten really close here: https://snack.expo.dev/@taustinligonier/f42d1f to get this working. I seem to be able to easily get the grid size I want (2x2, 3x3, etc...). However when it comes to adding a gap to only the middle part of the grid (no padding/margin on the outside) I have come to a complete stop.

I thought that doing `margin` on the children and `-margin` on the parent would work, but after some research negative margin on the bottom and right don't work the same as the top and left so I get some weird results (as in the wrapping no longer works for flex).

I could calculate the width of the item and use `justify-content: space-between`, but I think I can only do that horizontally or vertically not both with flex.

I can get this "working" with margin and padding but then there is spacing on the outside of the children which is what I don't want.

Maybe there is a way to add another container or something that would make it "look" like the children are touching the outer edge, but really they are not?

If you have any ideas I would be delighted to know! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think using flex on all components in a grid and using `justifyContent:'space-between'` are incompatible. Flex distribute the remaining width/height base upon the flex ratios and space-between  shares the remaining width/height  on the axis between all non first/last styled components. Because flex has already used the remaining width/height to increase the components size, then there will be no remaining width/height to use to add spacing between the components.

Here's where I realized [this](https://snack.expo.dev/q_9fXAH2X).

What I came up with was to apply margin to the opposite axis, e.g marginVertical is applied to the row, and marginHorizontal to columns. It works out [ok-ish](https://snack.expo.dev/e6slQo9mX):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { colorGenerator } from '@phantom-factotum/colorutils';
import Grid from './components/Grid';

const items = colorGenerator(11).map((color, i) => {
  return {
    title: 'Item' + (i + 1),
    color,
  };
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      <Grid
        rows={3}
        columns={4}
        items={items}
        containerStyle={{
          height: 400,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
          marginVertical: 15,
        }}
        rowStyle={{ marginVertical: 10 }}
        columnStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 5 }}
      />
      <Grid
        rows={4}
        columns={3}
        items={items}
        containerStyle={{
          height: 400,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
          marginVertical: 10,
        }}
        rowStyle={{ marginVertical: 20 }}
        columnStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 5 }}
      />
      <Grid
        rows={2}
        columns={6}
        items={items}
        containerStyle={{
          height: 400,
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
          marginVertical: 10,
        }}
        rowStyle={{ marginVertical: 20 }}
        columnStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 5 }}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

const isRowEdge = (i, totalRows) =>
  i % totalRows == 0 || i % totalRows == totalRows - 1;

export default function Grid({
  rows = 3,
  columns = 3,
  items,
  containerStyle,
  itemStyle,
  rowStyle,
  columnStyle,
}) {
  const initialValue = Array(rows)
    .fill([])
    .map(() => Array(columns).fill({}));
  let rowIx = 0;
  const renderRows = items.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
    let index = i % columns;
    if (i % columns == 0 && i > 0) {
      rowIx++;
    }
    prev[rowIx][index] = curr;
    return prev;
  }, initialValue);
  console.log('rows:', renderRows.length, '\ncolumns:', renderRows[0].length);
  return (
    <>
      <Text>
        Rows:{rows} Columns:{columns}
      </Text>
      <View style={[styles.container, containerStyle]}>
        {renderRows.map((cols) => {
          return (
            <View style={[styles.row, rowStyle]}>
              {cols.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <View
                    style={[
                      styles.col,
                      styles.item,
                      columnStyle,
                      { backgroundColor: item.color },
                      !item.title && styles.emptySpace,
                    ]}>
                    <Text>{item.title || ''}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    // flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: 2,
  },
  col: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: 2,
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
  },
  item: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  emptySpace: {
    borderWidth: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: Yeah, still the only issue is that there is margin on the top and left of the element's container. I tried to offset it for top and left, but didn't seem to work. As in the items don't go to the  edge on the top or left side of the colored containers! Still a good response though, thank you.

Comment: I think if you add the indices to the row and column map callbacks then all you can confirm if it’s the first/last row or cop column